# Return row with 0 for dates which has no entry in table - SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table that records daily sales data. However, there are days when no sale is made and hence there is no record on the database for those dates. Is it possible to extract data out from the table that returns null for these dates when no sale was made

[image: Sample view of the table that has the daily sales data by day and seller]

Referring to the image attached, it is seen there is no sales done on Jan 4 and Jan 8. I would like to write a SQL query that would return all dates from Jan 1 - Jan 10 but for Jan 4 and Jan 8, it should return 0 since there is no row for those dates (no sale done)

My date starts from Mar 1, 2018 and should go on for the next few quarters.

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Comment: Have a calendar table with all possible dates. right join.

Comment: The image also shows there is no entry for April 1, 1951. Do you want to look at a fixed data range? Or from the first date found in the table till the last date in it? Or from the first date found in the table till today? And you want to show all days including holidays and weekends, right?

Comment: Please don't use images. Paste the table as text.

Comment: `and should go on for the next few quarters.` is not very precise. So you  would be fine with a result showing all dates from March 1, 2018 to March, 31, 2019 (four quarters only), where almost all counts are null naturally? That doesn't seem to make much sense. And when you run your query in 2022 it shall start with March 1, 2018?

Comment: Hi Thorsten, my apologies would avoid using images moving forward. I have a requirement and hence mentioned the next few quarters as a rough time frame for which I would like to have this report running. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You haven't really answered my question. You say you don't want to select from table's first day till current day, but preferedly for a fixed time span, e.g. from March 1, 2018 till March 31, 2020. Yes? It just sounds weird to write a query so inflexible.

Comment: I see where you coming from, but my current request is to build data for this defined time frame. However if I could use the entire date range from the table, I shall use it and see if that's something the user might be interested in.

Comment: Missing: Postgres version, table definition showing data types and constraints, clear definition of requirements. And please post data as *text*, not as image.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  In Postgres, you can use `generate_series()` to generate dates or numbers within a range.

Then, you can use a `cross join` to generate the rows and then a `left join` to bring in the data:

```
select s.seller, gs.dte, t.count
from (select generate_series(mindate::timestamp, maxdate::timestamp, interval '1 day')::date
      from (select min(date) as mindate, max(date) as maxdate
            from t
           ) x
     ) gs(dte) cross join
     (select distinct seller from t) s left join
     t
     on t.date = gs.dte and t.seller = s.seller
```

Answer (score -1):

`CTE` is also an alternative here,

```
DECLARE @FDATE  DATE = '2018-01-01' 
        ,@TDATE DATE = '2018-01-10'

;WITH CTE_DATE
AS  (
    SELECT  @FDATE AS CDATE
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  DATEADD(DAY,1,CDATE)
    FROM    CTE_DATE
    WHERE   DATEADD(DAY,1,CDATE) <= @TDATE
)
SELECT  C.CDATE AS [DATE],COUNT(*)  AS [COUNT]
FROM    CTE_DATE AS C
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [MY_TABLE] AS M ON C.CDATE = M.[DATE] --*[your table here]*
GROUP BY C.CDATE
OPTION ( MAXRECURSION 0 );
```